How accurate are the election predictions by an incentivized pre-election survey?
For example, polymarket and other betting market constitute an incentivized survey. Most polls are not.
My question: how accurate are those incentivized election survey predictions?
By accuracy, I mean, how likely will the candidate with the highest price on the market (right before the election date) actually get elected.

It will obviously depend. In 2020 the markets followed the "red mirage" on election night, so not that much better. https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2020/12/trump-betting-markets-sportsbooks-offshore-2020-election-gambling.html

Also a (bet type) prediction is not (the only kind of) "an incentivized survey". The latter typically means you pay the respondents no matter the outcome or what they say.

@264champagnebottlesonice I mean the respondents are incentivized to give the correct outcome

@264champagnebottlesonice you are right. Nothing has 100% correction rate. So I am looking for data. Like outcome of 50 elections around the globe from 2018-2024, what percentages are corrected predicted by the bookies?
